# PySpark Cassandra Databese Connection Problem

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to use cassandra with pyspark. I can make a remote connection to Spark Server properly. But the stage of read cassandra table, I am in trouble. I tried all of datastax connectors, i changed Spark configs(core, memory, etc) but I couldnt accomplish it. (The comment rows in below code are my tries.)

Here is my python codes;

```
import os
os.environ['JAVA_HOME']="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271"
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME']="E:\etc\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7"
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON']="/usr/local/bin/python3.7"
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON']="/usr/local/bin/python3.7"

# os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=XX.XX.XX.XX spark.cassandra.auth.username=username spark.cassandra.auth.password=passwd pyspark-shell'
# os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars .ivy2\jars\spark-cassandra-connector-driver_2.12-3.0.0-alpha2.jar pyspark-shell'
# os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0-alpha2 pyspark-shell'

from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("spark://YY.YY.YY:7077").setAppName("My app")
conf.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "false")
conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","false")
conf.set("spark.executor.cores", "2")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "5g")
conf.set("spark.executor.instances", "1")
conf.set("spark.jars", "C:\\Users\\verianalizi\\.ivy2\\jars\\spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.0.0-beta.jar")

conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","XX.XX.XX.XX")
conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username","username")
conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password","passwd")
conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
# conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.myCatalog", "com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalog")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
# sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
list_p = [('John',19),('Smith',29),('Adam',35),('Henry',50)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(list_p)
ppl = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(name=x[0], age=int(x[1])))
DF_ppl = sqlContext.createDataFrame(ppl)

# It works well until now

def load_and_get_table_df(keys_space_name, table_name):
    table_df = sqlContext.read\
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
        .option("keyspace",keys_space_name)\
        .option("table",table_name)\
        .load()
    return table_df

movies = load_and_get_table_df("weather", "currentweatherconditions")
```

The error I get is;
[image: Error response]

Someone have any idea with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're specifying only `spark.jars` property, and pointing to the single jar. But spark cassandra connector depends on the number of the additional jars that aren't included into that list.  I recommend instead either use `spark.jars.packages` with coordinate `com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0`, or specify in `spark.jars` the path to the [assembly jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12/3.0.0) that has all necessary dependencies.

btw, 3.0 was release several months ago - why are you still using beta?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I tried below code and similar codes below

`os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0 pyspark-shell' `

But results is same.

Comment: I couldn't say about Jupyter

Comment: I found a solution. Of course using your info above.

`conf.set("spark.executor.jars", "C:\\Users\\verianalizi\\.ivy2\\jars\\spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.0.0.jar")

conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "C:\\Users\\verianalizi\\.ivy2\\jars\\spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.0.0.jar")
`